# Why is my screen component rendering twice if I use multiple useFocusEffects?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using two `useFocusEffect()` hooks (**from react-navigation-v6**).
When the screen presented in the code below is in focus, it is rendered **twice** instead of once as I'd expect it (the console.log() runs two times). Why is this happening?

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'

let renderCount = 0;

function TestScreen() {

  const [myState1, setMyState1] = useState<any>();
  const [myState2, setMyState2] = useState<any>();

  renderCount++;
  console.log("component render number: ", renderCount);

  // First useFocusEffect
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      fetchAPIData1()
    }, [])
  );

  // Second useFocusEffect
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      fetchAPIData2()
    }, [])
  );

  const fetchAPIData1 = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get<any>(
      'https://dummyjson.com/quotes?limit=30')
    setMyState2(data)
  }

  const fetchAPIData2 = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get<any>(
      'https://dummyjson.com/quotes?limit=30')
    setMyState2(data)
  }

  return (
    <View></View>
  )
}

export default TestScreen
```

Comment: Are you referring to the `console.log("component render number: ", renderCount);` in the function body as an unintentional side-effect? Yeah, don't use how many times this logs as any sort of accurate measure of component rendering as React can render the component any number of times to compute a diff before the conventional "render" to the DOM.

Comment: Yes. I thought that might be the case, but everywhere I read they said a simple console.log inside the component is enough. How could I actually find out if it's not doubled rendered inside the DOM? That's my concern.

Comment: Move the logs into a `useEffect` hook. One effect per render cycle. Are you having some specific issue in your code with component renders?

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior, both API calls should be executed in one effect, and it will still render twice since you're setting your state twice.

```
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      fetchAPIData1()
      fetchAPIData2()
    }, [])
);
```

If you want to have only one render you can Promise.all both of the API calls and set the state once, or you can leverage React.memo HOC to disable any unwanted visual changes during re-renders of children components.

#### Update

Make a container screen that will fetch the data, and extract your children JSX components into one or multiple components, wrap the children in React.memo and decide when each component should render, that way your container component will be responsible for fetching data and your children components will render only when their specific data is updated.

Comment: I simplified the use case, but actually I need multiple useFocusEffects because each should be triggered on different dependencies (not empty array). What exactly should I wrap inside React.memo?